# Getting all the Cache Names

Tags: java, hazelcast, jcache

I am developing a REST application to read all the caches in a Cluster that uses J Cache with Hazel cast 3.3.3

This application will create another hazel cast node when I call the following line in the application:

```
cacheManager= Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();
```

The node get clustered with already created nodes. But when I try to get all the cache names of the cluster with the following command, It returns an empty iterable:

```
cacheManager.getCacheNames().iterator()
```

I went through the Java doc of the Jcache which contained:

> May not provide all of the Caches managed by the CacheManager. For
>   example: Internally defined or platform specific Caches that may be
>   accessible by a call to getCache(java.lang.String) or
>   getCache(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class) may not be
>   present in an iteration.

But the caches that I am trying to access is not internally
 defined or platform specific. They are created by other nodes.

I want a way to get all the names present in the cluster. Is there a way to this?

NB: No hazelcast.xml is used in the application. All is initialized by the default xml s.

**Update:**

I can access the cache if I know the name. And after accessing for the first time by giving the name directly, now it shows that cache in the `cacheManager.getCacheNames().iterator()`

Answer (score 2):

`CacheManager` only provides names of caches it manages, so you cannot obtain all caches known to the cluster using JCache API.

In Hazelcast 3.7 (EA was released just yesterday), all `Cache`s are available as `DistributedObject`s, so invoking `HazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects()` and then checking for objects being instances of `javax.cache.Cache` or the Hazelcast-specific subclass `com.hazelcast.cache.ICache` you should be able to get references to all `Cache`s in the cluster:

```
// works for 3.7
Collection<DistributedObject> distributedObjects = hazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects();
for (DistributedObject distributedObject : distributedObjects) {
     if (distributedObject instanceof ICache) {
        System.out.println("Found cache with name " + distributedObject.getName());
     }
}
```

In Hazelcast 3.6 it is possible to obtain all cache names known to the cluster only using *internal* classes, so there is no guarantee this will work with any other version.

```
// works for 3.6 using internal classes, most probably will not work for other versions
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // start a hazelcast instance
    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

    // create a CacheManager and Cache on this instance
    CachingProvider hazelcastCachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider("com.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCachingProvider",
            HazelcastCachingProvider.class.getClassLoader());
    CacheManager cacheManager = hazelcastCachingProvider.getCacheManager();
    cacheManager.createCache("test1", new CacheConfig<Object, Object>());

    // hacky: obtain a reference to internal cache service
    CacheDistributedObject cacheDistributedObject = hz.getDistributedObject("hz:impl:cacheService", "setupRef");
    ICacheService cacheService = cacheDistributedObject.getService();

    // obtain all CacheConfig's in the cluster
    Collection<CacheConfig> cacheConfigs = cacheService.getCacheConfigs();
    for (CacheConfig cacheConfig : cacheConfigs) {
        System.out.println("Cache name: " + cacheConfig.getName() + 
            ", fully qualified name: " + cacheConfig.getNameWithPrefix());
    }

    hz.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But the caches that I am trying to access is not internally defined or
>   platform specific

Its good because this method should return all the others and some of the internally defined or platform specific ones.

Comment: He's correct. It returns all user defined caches but may leave out internal ones that are used for internal purposes.

Comment: But it does not return the names. I am not interested in internal caches. What I want are the caches created by other nodes.